# Unable to install gclient command in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, git, webrtc, apprtc

I am installing a command called **gclient** in Ubuntu 14.04. 
But It is not working and not giving any **error** message. 
I  clone command from the following repository

```
$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

Then I run the command given below

```
$ export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

When I run **gclient** command, it gives the following message

```
gwl@gwl-B85M-D3H:~/rajendra$ gclient
: No such file or directory
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please post your PATH: `$ echo $PATH`

Comment: `/home/gwl/rajendra/depot_tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: It should work as long as you have `gclient` in depot_tools folder. It is working for me now, just tested. Are you sure you are trying to run gclient in the same shell session where you did `export PATH=..` command?

Answer (score 0):

same issue I am facing.

I have  tried  to install **gclient** in **ubuntu 14.04** but it is not working, But when I tried in **ubuntu 16.04** it is working fine. 
please try  it in ubuntu 16.04 and enjoy your coding :)

Comment: It solves my problem but gclient is also working on Ubuntu 14.04 so that I do not think the problem is the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a session of terminal and export the path using this command.

```
export PATH=/path/to/depot_tools:$PATH
```

After that the gclient will be able to work only in that session of terminal.
Once you closed it then you have to manually set path again when you open terminal.

Answer (score 0):

We can export the desired path while exporting. Sample command to export the depot tools to home folder will look like below.

```
export PATH="$PATH:${HOME}/depot_tools"
```